# Can't access android class variable inside onListItemClick event

Tags: android, events, listview

I have a simple ListView and I have created a String array in the class and populated the array during the a custom createAdapter method.  The list works fine, but inside the onListItemClick event I can't access the array.

Is there a way to access the array?

Comment: can you show a bit of code? How is you array declared? How are you trying to access the array in onListItemClick?

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring it with the final modifier or changing the scope of the object to be "class scope" meaning, declare it global to the class.

Comment: The variable is declared at the beginning of the class:
String[] agentIDS;
Here is how I am trying to access it:
 protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
  super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
  Object o = this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
  //String keyword = o.toString();
  String keyword = agentIDS[position];
  Toast.makeText(this, "You selected: " + keyword ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }

Comment: I tried making it final and no luck; when I am inside the onListItemClick the variable is equal to null.

Comment: Is the create adapter being called?   And where is this onlistitemclick method, in the same class, or in an inner class, or anonymous interface?   Pls show more code